# Are GPTs close to real intelligence or just another Data In -Data Out -Data Permutation and Combinations?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, data, data-augmentation

Use cases and Solutions surrounding GPT's have taken NLP world with storm and started the GPT-Best vs GPT- Not So Best war on the internet. There are solutions been derived from API's provided by HF. What would be the impact and how feasible would be GPT development and deployment in the real world use case across domains?

Answer (score 1):

To answer that we Need to have a formal Definition of real intelligence. You got multiple definitions, but which one satisfies you?

Lets say you Claim real intelligence is Awareness. Than if you ask a machine can you prove to me that you are Aware you wont be satisfied. But can you prove you are Aware.

I mean at the end of the day it does not even matter. What matter is we are solving some specialised takes with GPTs a lot better than with other language models. Thats it. GTP(3) has a lot of flaws, just Google it.